# jQuery `is` is not a function

Tags: jquery

I have following HTML menu:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Index Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#some-page">Some Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Let say that `var url = "some-page";`

```
    $('#menu li a').prop('href')
                   .is('#' + url )
                   .parrent()
                   .addClass('active');
```

I'm keep getting error msg `.is is not a function`. Why? `.is` is clearly a function.

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: Carefully with "clearly is". Not every function is defined on every "type of object" - in this case, `typeof(String.prototype.is) == 'undefined'`

Comment: You have also spelled parent wrong. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `prop()` method you are calling before `is()` is returning the `href` property as a string.

Strings do not have an `is()` method.

Try;

```
$('#menu li a').filter('[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

Although you could combine this into one selector;

```
$('#menu li a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

Be aware that `is()` returns `true` or `false` if *any* of the matched elements matches the selector; so the following form could be used if you wanted to use `is()`;

```
$('#menu li a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is('[href="#' + url +'"]')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }
});
```

See the [`attribute` equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

[prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) returns if the property is set or its value, which means `true` or `false` or a string - and there's no `is()`-method on a boolean or a string.